# Calculate root of polynomial higher degree of specific form

Tags: polynomials, roots

Is there a way to calculate directly the root of a polynomial of the form:

$$a x^{n+1} + b x^{n} - 1 = 0, \quad a,b,x \in \mathbb{R}^{+}, n \in \mathbb{N}$$

Comment: Note that this is equivalent to $z^n=bz+a$, the intersection of a power law with a straight line.

Comment: If "directly" means "in radicals", see [this example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintic_function#Solvable_quintics).

Comment: With "directly", that I can write it down in some kind of expression without starting my numerical math engine.

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4463894/how-to-solve-xy-ax-b/4464966#4464966) out of many other similar ones for solving $x^y-ax+b=0$

Answer (score 0):

Here: let $x=1/z$ to obtain $$a+bz-z^{n+1}=0.$$ Then you can go several ways. One is $$z=\sqrt[n+1]{a+b\sqrt[n+1]{a+b\sqrt[n+1]{a+b(\cdots)}}}$$ provided this continued radical converges. The other such method is *[Series Reversion](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesReversion.html)*. Thus $$z=-b\sum_{n\geqslant 1}\frac{(2n-2)!}{n!(n-1)!}\frac{a^n}{b^{2n}}=-b(a/b^2+a^2/b^4+2a^3/b^6+\cdots)$$